# Can't disable required input for a Django TextField

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Currently, one of the text areas I'm working with is required to have input, I want to disable this behavior and make input optional. I'm using Wagtail, the relevant code is provided below.

```
description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Description")
```

From what I understand the form should *already* be optional due to the line above, I don't understand why I can't see the change in my application. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the code for your form?

Comment: I should probably clarify the question it's not a 'form' but a text input, the input itself is just a standard text area: django/forms/widgets/textarea.html

Comment: i'm not familiar with wagtail but maybe it's inherit from django form itself so try to add required=False to see if it work ?

Comment: Doesn't work with required=False. blank=True is more or less the equivalent of required=False for TextField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. The issue was caused by django-modeltranslation. For my default language (English), django-modeltranslation made all the fields mandatory and for the secondary language (Chinese) the fields were optional. The solution is to manually specify what you want to enable on a per-language basis since that will override the unintuitive default behavior.